# What's the best way to do a blur animation in OpenglES

Tags: opengl-es

I want to implement this effect in my OpenGL ES 2.0 driven iOS app: *the current scene blurs and fades out while the next scene fades in.*

the blurriness is animated, in other words, will changed rapidly in a moment.

I tried to use the *render to texture* technique to do the blurring (Render the scene down scaled to a texture and then render the texture fullscreen). But first of all, it's kind of slow to my observation. And secondly, the image will look screwed after resizing largely even using GL_LINEAR.

Then I tried to do it the shader way. I pass 9 texture coordinate varyings to the fragment shader, and blend them, the point distance larger when the blurriness is larger. The effect was bad when the blurriness is large, it just look like 9 transparent images cascading on the screen.

I'm kind of out of ideas. Is there any other more efficient and satisfiable way for me to implement this feature?

Comment: I experimented with various blur optimizations, and wrote about them here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu . The downsampling, blurring, then upsampling route seems to be the fastest means of getting a large-radius blur. You might be able to animate the texture spacing offset using something like that for reasonably good performance.